# Web Programming Frameworks Generating "//" for Links

Tags: html, http

Lately I've noticed that a lot of web programming frameworks are using a `//` in front of certain generated `href` and `src` links

```
//example from twitter.com
<a href="//support.twitter.com">Help</a>
```

Is this just a shortcut for `http`/`https`, or something more?

Does anyone know where this technique got its start and if there's a browser support matrix that confirms/describes the behavior of the leading `//`?

Comment: The behavior means "relative to app root" - as to where it got 'started', impossible to say.

Comment: @Tejs: No, that's the single slash behavior, it means "absolute" url instead of "relative".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's protocol-relative URL best described by Paul Irish; http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Basically if you use protocol relative URL's (links that start with "//" instead of "http://" or "https://") you can avoid the "This Page Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items" pop-up in Internet Explorer (and possibly on other browsers as well). You can use that in .css files, too, simply by changing "http://" or "https://" to "//".